# Function to transform lists of different lengths into data frame utilizing recycling

Tags: r, list, function

I'm trying to create a data frame with multiple areas where the rows are equal to the longest array in the list. Other arrays in the list then recycle the elements until they meet the longest number. I have to do this in a very specific way, using individual functions for each.

```
DF <- function(x) {
  maxLength <- listMax(x)
  newList <- listExtend(x,maxLength)
  finalList <- data.frame(newList)
  print(finalList)
}
```

The data frame in my function doesn't work because of the uneven numbers, which I assume stems from `newList` in the `DF` function. I can use a single loop, `sapply()`, `cbind()` or `rbind()` to transform the vectors and put them in data frame but each attempt has either resulted in all `1`s or other egregious issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you need to apply `listExtend` to each vector of `fullList` in the `DF` function.

```
x <- c(1:7)
y <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
z <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)
fullList <- list(x,y,z)


DF <- function(x) {
  maxLength <- max(lengths(x))
  newList <- lapply(x, function(l) rep(l, length.out = maxLength))
  finalDF <- data.frame(newList)
  return(finalDF)
}


outDF <- DF(fullList)
colnames(outDF) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
outDF
#------
  x y     z
1 1 a  TRUE
2 2 b  TRUE
3 3 c FALSE
4 4 d FALSE
5 5 e  TRUE
6 6 a  TRUE
7 7 b FALSE
```

Comment: I think you've made this too complicated. `listMax` can be replaced by `lengths`, which can be used directly in `rep` in your `lapply` call. I also wouldn't hard-code the creation of names in your function.

Comment: Thanks for some good suggestions. Was not aware of `lengths`.